# pd.to_datetime() DateParseError when run in Airflow

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, airflow

**Goal**

Date field [YYYY-MM-DD] comes into a dataframe via `pd.read_sql()`. Because of destination system constraints, the field needs to be created as a datetime string. Then it is reformatted as a datetime so it can be uploaded to BigQuery. The entirety of the script is being run via Airflow

**Error**

The following error only occurs when the script is triggered from Airflow. *Manually running the script produces no errors.*

> [2024-01-10T15:52:06.801-0500] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - df['tx_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tx_date_time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
> pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.DateParseError: Unknown datetime string
> format, unable to parse: 2024-01-02 00:00%:00, at position 0

**Script/Process**

```
import pandas as pd

#sample data coming from pd.read_sql
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tx_date_time'] = ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-04']

#error appears to occur here
df['tx_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tx_date_time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

#convert to a datetime object
df['tx_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tx_date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Did you notice the `%` in the exception : `2024-01-02 00:00%:00`?

Comment: @Corralien. Yes, I'm unable to determine what's causing it.